# Performing a subquery on a resultset in oracle to create an XML

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xml-parsing

I have the following type of result set returned from the database in Oracle:

```
**Name    Type  SubName        Number**
test    B     tim            1
test    B     jfd            2
testV   I     rr             1
testV   I     sim            2
dsgsg   B     sgsg           1
dsgsg   B     sfsfssfsffs    2
```

What I want is to manipulate this result using SQL to create an XML of this type

```
<NameList>
<Name/>
<Type/>
<SubNameList>
<SubName>
<Name/>
<Number/>
</SubName>
</SubNameList>
</NameList>
```

Eg: For first two records of result set have same Name so the XML will be:

```
<NameList>
<Name>test</Name>
<Type>B</Type>
<SubNameList>
<SubName>
<Name>tim</Name>
<Number>1</Number>
</SubName>
<SubName>
<Name>jfd</Name>
<Number>2</Number>
</SubName>
</SubNameList>
</NameList>
```

**What I have done so far:**
I have two tables as:

```
TABLE1
    **ID NAME  KEY**
      1  test  101
      1  testV 102
      1  dsgsg 103

TABLE2   
    **ID SUBNAME TYPE NUMBER KEY**
      1  tim     B    1      101
      1  jfd     B    2      101
      1  rr      I    1      102
      1  sim     I    2      102
      1  sgsg    B    1      103
      1  sfsfssfsffs B 2     103
```

SQL:

```
Select A.NAME, B.TYPE, B.SUBNAME, B.NUMBER
FROM TABLE1 A INNER JOIN TABLE2 B
ON A.ID = B.ID WHERE A.ID = '1';
```

I have created the XML using XMLELEMENT() in oracle as:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE NAME_XML XMLTYPE;
v_offset number := 1;
v_chunk_size number := 255;
BEGIN
Select XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("NAMELIST",
XMLELEMENT("Name", A.NAME),
XMLELEMENT("Type", B.TYPE),
XMLELEMENT("SubName", B.SUBNAME),
XMLELEMENT("Number", B.NUMBER)))
INTO NAME_XML 
FROM TABLE1 A INNER JOIN TABLE2 B
ON A.ID = B.ID WHERE A.ID = '1';

loop
    exit when v_offset > dbms_lob.getlength(NAME_XML.getClobVal());
    dbms_output.put_line( dbms_lob.substr(NAME_XML.getClobVal(), 
    v_chunk_size, v_offset ) );
    v_offset := v_offset + v_chunk_size;
end loop; 
END;
```

The XML is getting created of this type:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <NAMELIST>
      <Name>test</Name>
      <Type>B</Type>
      <SubName>tim</SubName>
      <Number>1</Number>
   </NAMELIST>
.
.
.
.
.
   <NAMELIST>
      <Name>dsgsg</Name>
      <Type>B</Type>
      <SubName>sfsfssfsffs</SubName>
      <Number>2</Number>
   </NAMELIST>
</root>
```

How can I achieve the XML format of this type:

```
<NameList>
<Name>test</Name>   
<Type>B</Type>
<SubNameList>
<SubName>
<Name>tim</Name>
<Number>1</Number>
</SubName>
<SubName>
<Name>jfd</Name>            
<Number>2</Number>
</SubName>
</SubNameList>
</NameList>
....
....
....
....
```

Any inputs will be helpful.

Comment: @jarlh I'm using Oracle and removed the mysql tag from it

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your table so I select some fixed values from dual. There's no pretty printed output.

```
declare
   name_xml     xmltype;
   v_offset     number := 1;
   v_chunk_size number := 255;
begin
    select xmlagg(xmlelement("NAMELIST"
                            ,xmlelement("Name", 'Peter')
                            ,xmlelement("Type", 'mytype')
                            ,xmlelement("SubName", 'SUBNAME', xmlelement("Number", 'B.NUMBER'))))
     into name_xml
     from dual;

   loop
      exit when v_offset > dbms_lob.getlength(name_xml.getclobval());
      dbms_output.put_line(dbms_lob.substr(name_xml.getclobval(), v_chunk_size, v_offset));
      v_offset := v_offset + v_chunk_size;
   end loop;
end;


<NAMELIST><Name>Peter</Name><Type>mytype</Type><SubName>SUBNAME<Number>B.NUMBER</Number></SubName></NAMELIST>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use procedure as this one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MakePrettyXml(xmlString IN OUT NOCOPY CLOB, intent IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'yes') IS

    xmlDocFragment DBMS_XMLDOM.DOMDOCUMENTFRAGMENT;
    xslProc DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.PROCESSOR;
    xsl DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.STYLESHEET;
    xmlStringOut CLOB;

BEGIN

    DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(xmlStringOut, TRUE);
    xslProc := DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.NEWPROCESSOR; 
    xsl := DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.NEWSTYLESHEET(
        '<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">'||
            '<xsl:output method="xml" indent="'||intent||'"/>'||
            '<xsl:template match="@*|node( )">'||
                '<xsl:copy>'||
                    '<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node( )"/>'||
                '</xsl:copy>'||
            '</xsl:template>'||
        '</xsl:stylesheet>', NULL);

    xmlDocFragment := DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.PROCESSXSL(p => xslProc, ss => xsl, cl => xmlString);
    DBMS_XMLDOM.WRITETOCLOB(DBMS_XMLDOM.MAKENODE(xmlDocFragment), xmlStringOut);

    DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.FREESTYLESHEET(xsl);
    DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.FREEPROCESSOR(xslProc);

    xmlString := xmlStringOut; 
    DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY(xmlStringOut);

END MakePrettyXml;
```

Result:

```
DECLARE
    xmlString CLOB := '<root><NAMELIST>
      <Name>test</Name><Type>B</Type><SubName>tim</SubName><Number>1</Number>
   </NAMELIST>
   <NAMELIST>
      <Name>dsgsg</Name>
      <Type>B</Type><SubName>sfsfssfsffs</SubName>
      <Number>2</Number>
   </NAMELIST>
</root>';

BEGIN

    MakePrettyXml(xmlString, 'no');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(xmlString);

    MakePrettyXml(xmlString);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(xmlString);

END;

<root>
<NAMELIST>
<Name>test</Name>
<Type>B</Type>
<SubName>tim</SubName>
<Number>1</Number>
</NAMELIST>
<NAMELIST>
<Name>dsgsg</Name>
<Type>B</Type>
<SubName>sfsfssfsffs</SubName>
<Number>2</Number>
</NAMELIST>
</root>

<root>
  <NAMELIST>
    <Name>test</Name>
    <Type>B</Type>
    <SubName>tim</SubName>
    <Number>1</Number>
  </NAMELIST>
  <NAMELIST>
    <Name>dsgsg</Name>
    <Type>B</Type>
    <SubName>sfsfssfsffs</SubName>
    <Number>2</Number>
  </NAMELIST>
</root>
```

**Update**

I hope your question is related to XML content, not the format. In this case try (not tested)

```
Select XMLELEMENT("NameList", 
   XMLELEMENT("Name", A.NAME),
   XMLELEMENT("Type", B.TYPE),
   XMLELEMENT("SubNameList", 
     XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("SubName", 
     XMLELEMENT("Name", B.NAME)
     XMLELEMENT("Number", B.NUMBER))))
   )
INTO NAME_XML 
FROM TABLE1 A INNER JOIN TABLE2 B
ON A.ID = B.ID WHERE A.ID = '1';
```

Answer (score 0):

I can get this..

```
SQL> set pages 0
SQL> WITH TABLE1 AS
  2  (
  3  SELECT 1 AS ID, 'test' as NAME, 101 as KEY
  4    from DUAL
  5   UNION ALL
  6  SELECT 1 AS ID, 'testV' as NAME, 102 as KEY
  7    from DUAL
  8   UNION ALL
  9  SELECT 1 AS ID, 'dsgsg' as NAME, 103 as KEY
 10    from DUAL
 11  ),
 12  TABLE2 as
 13  (
 14  SELECT 1 AS ID, 'tim' as SUBNAME, 'B' as TYPE, 1 as "NUMBER",101 as KEY
 15    from DUAL
 16   UNION ALL
 17  SELECT 1 AS ID, 'jfd' as SUBNAME, 'B' as TYPE, 2 as "NUMBER",101 as KEY
 18    from DUAL
 19   UNION ALL
 20  SELECT 1 AS ID, 'rr' as SUBNAME, 'I' as TYPE, 1 as "NUMBER",102 as KEY
 21    from DUAL
 22   UNION ALL
 23  SELECT 1 AS ID, 'sim' as SUBNAME, 'I' as TYPE, 2 as "NUMBER",102 as KEY
 24    from DUAL
 25   UNION ALL
 26  SELECT 1 AS ID, 'sgsg' as SUBNAME, 'B' as TYPE, 1 as "NUMBER",103 as KEY
 27    from DUAL
 28   UNION ALL
 29  SELECT 1 AS ID, 'sfsfssfsffs' as SUBNAME, 'B' as TYPE, 2 as "NUMBER", 103 as KEY
 30    from DUAL
 31  )
 32  select XMLSERIALIZE(DOCUMENT
 33           xmlElement("NameList",
 34             xmlElement("Name", NAME),
 35        xmlElement(
 36               "SubNameList",(
 37                 select xmlAgg(
 38                          xmlElement(
 39                            "SubName",
 40                               XMLELEMENT("Name", SUBNAME),
 41                               XMLELEMENT("Number", "NUMBER"),
 42                               XMLELEMENT("Type", TYPE)
 43                          )
 44                        )
 45                   from TABLE2 T2
 46                  where T2.ID = T1.ID
 47             ))
 48           )
 49           AS VARCHAR2(4000) INDENT SIZE=2
 50         )
 51    from TABLE1 T1
 52   WHERE T1.ID = '1'
 53  /
<NameList>
  <Name>test</Name>
  <SubNameList>
    <SubName>
      <Name>tim</Name>
      <Number>1</Number>
      <Type>B</Type>
    </SubName>
    <SubName>
      <Name>jfd</Name>
      <Number>2</Number>
      <Type>B</Type>
    </SubName>
    <SubName>
      <Name>rr</Name>
      <Number>1</Number>
      <Type>I</Type>
    </SubName>
    <SubName>
      <Name>sim</Name>
      <Number>2</Number>
      <Type>I</Type>
    </SubName>
    <SubName>
      <Name>sgsg</Name>
      <Number>1</Number>
      <Type>B</Type>
    </SubName>
    <SubName>
      <Name>sfsfssfsffs</Name>
      <Number>2</Number>
      <Type>B</Type>
    </SubName>
  </SubNameList>
</NameList>

<NameList>
  <Name>testV</Name>
  <SubNameList>
    <SubName>
      <Name>tim</Name>
      <Number>1</Number>
      <Type>B</Type>
    </SubName>
    <SubName>
      <Name>jfd</Name>
      <Number>2</Number>
      <Type>B</Type>
    </SubName>
    <SubName>
      <Name>rr</Name>
      <Number>1</Number>
      <Type>I</Type>
    </SubName>
    <SubName>
      <Name>sim</Name>
      <Number>2</Number>
      <Type>I</Type>
    </SubName>
    <SubName>
      <Name>sgsg</Name>
      <Number>1</Number>
      <Type>B</Type>
    </SubName>
    <SubName>
      <Name>sfsfssfsffs</Name>
      <Number>2</Number>
      <Type>B</Type>
    </SubName>
  </SubNameList>
</NameList>

<NameList>
  <Name>dsgsg</Name>
  <SubNameList>
    <SubName>
      <Name>tim</Name>
      <Number>1</Number>
      <Type>B</Type>
    </SubName>
    <SubName>
      <Name>jfd</Name>
      <Number>2</Number>
      <Type>B</Type>
    </SubName>
    <SubName>
      <Name>rr</Name>
      <Number>1</Number>
      <Type>I</Type>
    </SubName>
    <SubName>
      <Name>sim</Name>
      <Number>2</Number>
      <Type>I</Type>
    </SubName>
    <SubName>
      <Name>sgsg</Name>
      <Number>1</Number>
      <Type>B</Type>
    </SubName>
    <SubName>
      <Name>sfsfssfsffs</Name>
      <Number>2</Number>
      <Type>B</Type>
    </SubName>
  </SubNameList>
</NameList>


SQL>
SQL>
```

But I am not sure How TYPE is meant to figure into the required result..